# Publishing Crystal Report using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm using Visual studio 2010 and want to deliver a crystal report as a web service. I don't see the feature to right-click a .rpt file and publish as web service in VS2010. Any help will be highly appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

- 1 create a WebService project
- 2 add references to CR (also add or create your report .rpt File)
- 3 If you have in parameters set them.
- 4 Code the logic to render the report into your WebService (database access if needed).
- 5 Use report.ExportTostream(type of file you want) as return data (depending on the result you want your web service to have, you may have to wrap the data into an HTTP Response or something alike.)

see : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182557.aspx and 
http://forums.asp.net/t/1597083.aspx/1 as references